# Hive from_unixtime() generating inappropriate date

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using a query to generate timestamp from a dummy table called dual.But, the date returned from the table seems to be invalid.

```
select String(max(max_lid_date)) as prev_reqline_max_lid_date,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') as job_start_date,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:01') as pull_to_date from xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log;
```

Result of the query:

```
prev_reqline_max_lid_date       job_start_date  pull_to_date
1970-01-01 00:00:00     2015-12-349 01:47:52    2015-12-349 00:00:01
```

Dual table structure:

```
hive (smart_advisor)> desc dual;
OK
col_name        data_type       comment
id               string
```

Structure of the hive table from which the date is being retrieved

```
hive (smart_advisor)> desc xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log;
OK
col_name        data_type       comment
job_start_date          timestamp
job_end_date            timestamp
pull_from_date          timestamp
pull_to_date            timestamp
min_lid_date            timestamp
max_lid_date            timestamp
record_count            bigint
```

Need help in resolving the date issue in the pull_to_date and job_start_date column. This is a log table for my job.

The table xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log contains only one record

```
hive (smart_advisor)> select * from xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log;
OK
xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log.job_start_date    xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log.job_end_date      xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log.pull_from_date    xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log.pull_to_date       xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log.min_lid_date      xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log.max_lid_date      xxcss_ktn_req_line_detail_log.record_count
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1970-01-01 00:00:00     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong format string.
In particular, you're using capital D (Day in year) instead of lowercase 'd'.
You probably want also capital H instead of lowercase h since in lowercase it's 12 hour am/pm time.

Try instead

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:01')
      from single_customer;
OK
2015-12-15 00:00:01
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')  
from single_customer;
OK
2015-12-15 08:25:22
```

Notice that 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' is the default so you could just use

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) from single_customer;
OK
2015-12-15 08:27:16
```

Hive uses of course Java for date formats so you should check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html